# Prime calculation formula does not shows prime number till 100000 it show till 9973

Tags: java, arrays

```
long i = 0;
int primeNumberCounter = 1;
long upperLimit = 100000;
PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
while (++i <= upperLimit) {
    long i1 = (long) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(i));
    boolean isPrimeNumber = false;
    while (i1 > 1) {
        if ((i != i1) && (i % i1 == 0)) {
            isPrimeNumber = false;
            break;
        } else if (!isPrimeNumber) {
            isPrimeNumber = true;
        }
        --i1;
    }

    if (isPrimeNumber) {
        writer.write(String.valueOf(i));
        writer.write("\n");
        ++primeNumberCounter;
    }
}
```

I deployed above code on google app engine.I am getting value till 9973 not 99991 which must be last prime number.Thanx any help appreciated

Comment: Where did you get this algorithm? It's terrible. Look up the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call

```
writer.close();
```

at the end, after your while loop to flush all your data. Or if you still be using `writer`, call `writer.flush()`.

Comment: Where to use writer.flush and writer.close() method.After while or at the end of while loop?

Comment: and use only one, `close()` and `flush()` both flush your data, but `close()` also close your writer and you will have to manually open again if you are using it.

Comment: mmm... try with `writer.println(i);` instead of `writer.write(String.valueOf(i));
        writer.write("\n");`, also, how do you declare `resp`?

Comment: Once the writer flushed and closed, this code works as expected, see http://ideone.com/2OgQbS (used `System.out` and not the servlet output)

Comment: @ayeshaabdulmajeed the only thing I could think is call `flush()` after every `write()` or `print()` you do, maybe is something related to the `HttpServletResponse resp` object but I am not too sure...